# merge two lists by some map key

Tags: clojure

I'd like to merge two lists by some map key as follow:

```
(def list1 '({:a 2 :b 2} {:a 1 :b 1}))
(def list2 '({:a 1 :c 1} {:a 2 :c 2}))
```

As result I'd like something like, using sort by :a for example:

```
'({:a 1 :b 1 :c 1} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 2})
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do it?

```
(def list1 '({:a 1 :b 1} {:a 2 :b 2}))
(def list2 '({:a 1 :c 1} {:a 2 :c 2}))

(println
  (map merge list1 list2)
)

;=> ({:a 1, :b 1, :c 1} {:a 2, :b 2, :c 2})
```

UPDATE

```
(def list1 [ {:a 1 :b 1} {:a 2 :b 2} ] )
(def list2 [ {:a 2 :c 2} {:a 1 :c 1} ] )

(defn sort-merge [lista listb]
  (map merge (sort-by :a lista) (sort-by :a listb)))
(println
  (sort-merge list1 list2))

;=> ({:a 1, :b 1, :c 1} {:a 2, :b 2, :c 2})
```

Comment: these maps in lists might not be in order. I've just made an edit.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `join` and `sort-by`:

```
(:require '[clojure.set :as s])
(sort-by :a (s/join list1 list2 {:a :a}))
```

Answer (score 1):

another way is to use list comprehension:

```
user> (for [x list1
            y list2
            :when (= (:a x) (:a y))]
        (merge x y))

({:a 2, :b 2, :c 2} {:a 1, :b 1, :c 1})
```